# Launchd script to mount volume on boot

Tags: macos, bash, launchd, mount, plist

I have a script `monta.sh` to mount an external volume:

```
#!bin/sh
mkdir -p /Volumes/remvol
mount_smbfs //user:password@server/folder /Volumes/remvol
```

Then I have a `com.jo.monta.plist` to launch the script after system boot placed in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.jo.monta</string>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>admin</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/admin/scripts/monta.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've tested the script from the command line and it works, however if I log in after boot the volume is not mounted.

It seems like the plist file doesn't load? what's wrong?

Comment: Small correction to the script: `#!bin/sh` should be `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: Do you see any output in `system.log` regarding this launchd job? You can see the contents of `system.log` using **Applications > Utilities > Console.app**.

Comment: @GrahamMiln Thanks, I corrected my script. I haven't seen any reference to `com.jo.monta` in the system log, I have also used `launchctl list | grep monta` to see if there was something and no reference neither.

Comment: Why are you using `ProgramArguments` instead of `Program` (which is a simple key/value pair, not an array, see `man launchd.plist` for details)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script and the plist work perfectly well if you make following changes:

add a slash in /Users/admin/scripts/monta.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p /Volumes/remvol
mount_smbfs //user:password@server/folder /Volumes/remvol
```

proper ownership of com.jo.monta.plist:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.jo.monta.plist
```

proper file mode bits of /Users/admin/scripts/monta.sh:

```
chmod 755 /Users/admin/scripts/monta.sh
```

load the launch daemon:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.jo.monta.plist
```

Comment: @naio Try `chmod 755 /Users/admin/scripts/monta.sh`